# increasing a logical volume

Tags: centos, partition, directory, hard-disk, directory-structure

I need to increase the logical volume of the `var` directory, the maximum size of `var` right now is 10GB, I need to make it 50GB. I have a Centos 6 server.

The output of `df -h` is:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                 10G   10G     0 100% /
/dev/root              10G   10G     0 100% /
none                  991M  312K  990M   1% /dev
/dev/sda2             455G  3.6G  429G   1% /home
tmpfs                 991M     0  991M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/root              10G   10G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/etc/named
/dev/root              10G   10G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/var/named
/dev/root              10G   10G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.conf
/dev/root              10G   10G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.rfc1912.zones
/dev/root              10G   10G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/etc/rndc.key
/dev/root              10G   10G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/usr/lib64/bind
/dev/root              10G   10G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.iscdlv.key
/dev/root              10G   10G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.root.key
```

I followed [this tutorial](http://faq.1and1.com/dedicated_servers/root_server/linux_admin_help/7.html). In order to increase the volume you have to do:

`lvextend -L +40G /Path/To/var`

My problem is simple, I don't know where my var is located.

If i do `lvextend -L +40G /dev/root/var` I get `Volume group "root" not found`

If i do `lvextend -L +40G /dev/var` I get

```
  Path required for Logical Volume "var"
  Please provide a volume group name
  Run `lvextend --help' for more information.
```

I tried every possible path, still can't find the right path to var, so where my `var` is located?

**EDIT**

If i do `lvextend -L +40G /dev/root` I get

```
  Path required for Logical Volume "root"
  Please provide a volume group name
  Run `lvextend --help' for more information.
```

`pvs` gives no output at all.

`lvs` gives this output `No volume groups found`

Comment: Can you add the output of pvs, vgs and lvs please.

Comment: @DennisKaarsemaker I just did, sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I expected from the name `/dev/root`, you're not using LVM. You have a few options:

1. Reinstall
2. Hope that your partitioning scheme allows you to grow the root partition with (g)parted.
3. Create a new partition as LVM volume, create a vg and and an lv for /var and move /var over
4. Clean up the current system so you don't need the space

Options 2 and 3 are best done when booting from a rescue cd or rescue netboot.

Comment: option 1: do you mean reinstall centos? if so what to do during the installation to insure that i'm using lvm volume? Basically i have nothing on the server right now so i can do a reinstallation

Answer (score 1):

Your `/var` is inside the root mountpoint, so you'll want to increase the size of `/dev/root`, if that is an LVM volume.

Comment: please read my edit sir

Comment: Or use something like [parted](http://www.gnu.org/software/parted), as OP isn't using LVM.